# Returning value from shared pointer vector string

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement a return method for a class I want to use smart pointers. I have:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> data;
```

I want to access its last value with this function:

```
std::string& rear()
    {

    };
```

How do I access values with the shared_ptr?

Comment: return data->at(data->size() - 1); in curly brackets, is this the right way?

Comment: Any reason you have `std::shared_ptr<vector<stting>>` ?

Comment: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> because I want to implement my class with C++ 11 ways of doing things because it's safer

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` already safe ( in terms of automatic memory management ). You don't get any extra benifit by making it wrapped in a `std::shared_ptr` ;

Answer (score 4):

SImply return the last element from the array after dereferencing the pointer. The member function [std::vector::back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) would return the element from the end of the vector which is also the last element.

It is worth noting, that smart pointers are pointer wrappers, which generally supports the operations that you would have done on C pointers, which includes dereferencing `*` and member access via dereferencing  `->`.

```
std::string& rear()
{
    if (data && ! data.empty ())
        return data->back();
    else
        // Your Error Handling Should Go Here
        ;
};
```

Comment: I think it should be if (data.get() && ...)

Comment: @rozina: I think that may not be required as a [bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) check should invoke the get member function.

Comment: use empty () instead if size () > 0 check

Comment: @rozina You don't need `get` to check the validity of the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this:

```
std::string& rear()
{
    assert(data.get() != 0 && !data->empty());
    return *(*data).rbegin();
};
```

- `*data` is a vector
- `(*data).rbegin()` returns a reverse iterator pointing to the last element
- `*(*data).rbegin()` dereferences the iterator, getting its value (a reference)

Comment: I have been using std::string a lot lately and I forgot std::vector has a back() member function :) Use Abhijit solution imo, its simpler and more clear :)